# How powerful should a magnet be to be able to pick the cans from the floor?

Tags: electromagnetism

I bought a 4 W Electromagnet to collect aluminium cans laying on the floor. A can weighs around 0.015 kg. I read aluminium is only paramagnetic. And playing manually with the current magnet, I cannot appreciate any force being exerted to the aluminium can.

How powerful should a magnet be to be able to pick the cans from the floor? 
(let's say, from 10 cm away?)

Comment: Wood is also para-magnetic, as is air. Are you planning on picking them up with a magnet too? I suspect that by the time your magnet is strong enough to pick up a can it'll also be strong enough to pull out any iron nails holding the floor together.

Comment: **Strong** electromagnets are used at recycling plant to remove magnetic metals like iron & steel that may contaminate collections aluminum cans

Comment: Things to think about that may help to formulate an answer: How much iron does the relevant grade of aluminium contain as an impurity?  Is that iron in a solid solution within the aluminium crystals, or is the iron segregated into its own crystals?  If the iron is segregated into its own crystals, are those crystals big enough to be ferromagnetic?

Comment: Strong electromagnets are also used to separate non-magnetic metals like aluminum from plastic. But they don't act on principle of magnetic attraction, just on inducing eddy currents - aluminum and plastic mix is shot at high speed through a strong magnetic field, which inducing current in the quickly moving conductor slows it down and makes it fall into a different bin than the plastic.

Answer (score 1):

A magnet will never be able to "pick up" an aluminum object, no matter how strong.

To move aluminum with a magnet, you have to subject it to a *changing* magnetic field. This field will produce eddy currents in the aluminum, which will in turn create a magnetic field around the can, which will then oppose (repel) the magnetic field which induced the eddy currents.

Practically speaking that means if set an empty can on a table, and swung a very powerful magnet past it, you might move the can a little.

If the can and magnet were stationary relative to each other, nothing would happen.

If you used an electromagnet instead and brought it near the can then turned it on, the can would be *briefly* repulsed.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out THERE IS a magnetic way to separate aluminium.

> When a piece of nonferrous metal, such as aluminum, passes over the
> separator, the magnets inside the shell rotate past the aluminum at
> high speed. This forms eddy currents in the aluminum, which in turn
> create a magnetic field around the piece of aluminum.

Comment: And then what? Can we use that to attract the cans to the same rotating magnets or do we need others?

Comment: @Transistor well, a large enough eddy current can cause the aluminum to melt  then it can be collected in a container by gravity... :) most efficient?

Comment: @Solar, Yes, that might work but it's unlikely to be efficient compared with picking up steel with a simple magnet or electromagnet. I'm not being critical - just thinking ...

Comment: @Transistor I'm not getting at you, sorry - just trying to get the answerer to think a bit...

Comment: No problem. I didn't think you were.

Comment: At best you can cause a deflection.

Comment: @SolarMike it doesn't melt. you can see it here in action https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K2KKmh-CYTg

Comment: @Pep "large enough~" did you not get it?

Comment: well, your comment sounded like a downvote to my approach. so if i just defend my approach, there's no need for you to treat others as if stupid.

Comment: @Pep Interesting video. You should add it to your answer. Eddy currents can provide a transient force on the aluminum can, but it won’t allow a magnet to pick up and hold a can.